# java.lang.ClassCastException: net.kencochrane.raven.log4j.SentryAppender cannot be cast to org.apache.log4j.Appender

Tags: java, log4j, sentry, raven

I'm trying to use [raven-log4j](https://github.com/getsentry/raven-java/tree/master/raven-log4j) to send [youtrack](https://www.jetbrains.com/youtrack/)'s exception to the [Sentry](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry).

`/etc/youtrack/log4j.xml`:

```
<appender name="sentry" class="net.kencochrane.raven.log4j.SentryAppender">
  <param name="dsn" value="https://publicKey:secretKey@host:port/1"/>
  <filter class="org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelRangeFilter">
    <param name="levelMin" value="WARN"/>
  </filter>
</appender>

<root>
    <priority value="INFO"/>
    <appender-ref ref="SYSLOG"/>
    <appender-ref ref="sentry"/>
</root>
```

A part of the original upstart file:

> exec java -Xmx{{ heap_size }} -XX:MaxPermSize=250m
>   -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djetbrains.youtrack.disableBrowser=true -Djava.security.egd=/dev/zrandom -Djetbrains.mps.webr.log4jPath=/etc/youtrack/log4j.xml -jar /usr/local/youtrack/{{ jarfile }} 8082

and I changed it to:

> exec java -Xmx1g -XX:MaxPermSize=250m -Djava.awt.headless=true
>   -Djetbrains.youtrack.disableBrowser=true -Djava.security.egd=/dev/zrandom -Djetbrains.mps.webr.log4jPath=/etc/youtrack/log4j.xml -cp /usr/local/youtrack/youtrack-6.5.16853.jar:/usr/local/youtrack/lib/*
>   jetbrains.youtrack.standalone.YoutrackStandalone 8082

to specify the classpath (`/usr/local/youtrack/lib/*`).

Without copying `raven-log4j-6.0.0.jar` to `/usr/local/youtrack/lib`, I will get an error like this:

```
log4j: Class name: [net.kencochrane.raven.log4j.SentryAppender]
log4j:ERROR Could not create an Appender. Reported error follows.
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: net.kencochrane.raven.log4j.SentryAppender
```

but after put it into that lib folder, another error appear:

```
log4j: Class name: [net.kencochrane.raven.log4j.SentryAppender]
log4j:ERROR Could not create an Appender. Reported error follows.
java.lang.ClassCastException: net.kencochrane.raven.log4j.SentryAppender cannot be cast to org.apache.log4j.Appender
```

Sure, there is no `log4j-*.jar` in the `lib` folder:

```
ls -l /usr/local/youtrack/lib/
total 88
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 79444 Jan  7 14:13 raven-6.0.0.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  6798 Jan  7 14:35 raven-log4j-6.0.0.jar
```

Why and where was it loaded twice?

Answer (score 0):

This was resolved on [GitHub](https://github.com/getsentry/raven-java/issues/169)

> One thing worth noting is that you'll still need to include manually add the additional dependencies of both raven (https://github.com/getsentry/raven-java/tree/master/raven#manual-dependency-management) and raven-log4j (https://github.com/getsentry/raven-java/tree/master/raven-log4j#manual-dependency-management) that are not already included by YouTrack (e.g. Jackson, Guava, etc.) since we don't assemble or shade these dependencies with the raven JARs. I don't that think this would be causing the issue, though.
>
> Also, from what I could tell, log4j was also initialized twice by the application (log line: Init web application log4j location: /tmp/youtrack-example/log4j.xml.) The first invocation would always fail with a ClassCastException, while the second would fail to initialize a Raven instance via the RavenFactory (included below.) Both using the automatically registered factory provided by ServiceLoader and explicitly providing a factory yield the same result.